# How to insert data taken from user into mysql using jdbc

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'd like to get a data (e.g. name) from user and insert it into mysql using JDBC.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
String uName = Username.getText(); (where uName is the name of the texfield)
```

Then I'd like to insert this 'uName' variable into mysql. I knew it wouldnt work, but I gave it a shot, and tried to do it with the following query:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO users(username) VALUES(uName)");
```

(Where username is the name of the column.)

It didnt work :) Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggest you read about SQL injection and parameterised statements, e.g.: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are opening connection to your database in the right way, you can do something like:

```
String connString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<db_name>?user=<user>&password=<password>";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connString);

// open connection
// ...

try 
{
  String query = "INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (" + uName + ")"
  statement = connect.createStatement();
  statement.executeUpdate(query);
}
catch (SQLException se)
{
  es.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I got this after i compiled what you've written;   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Koray' in 'field list'             where Koray is what the user typed in the texfield(username).

Comment: Question solved: I should have used prepared statements. I did the following:                              PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Users(username) VALUES(?)"); 
            ps.setString(1, username);
            ps.executeUpdate(); and it worked.